# Ad hoc queries against high cardinality columns

Tags: sql, oracle

How to improve the performance of ad hoc queries against tables having hundreds of high cardinality columns and millions of records?

In my case, I have a table with one indexed `DATE` column `SDATE`, one `VARCHAR2` column `NE` and 750 numeric columns most of them high cardinality columns with values in the range of `0 to 100`. The table is updated with almost `20000` new records every hour. The queries against this table look like:

```
SELECT * FROM TAB WHERE SDATE BETWEEN :SDATE AND :EDATE AND V1 > :V1 AND V3 < :V3
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM TAB WHERE SDATE BETWEEN :SDATE AND :EDATE AND NE = :NE AND V4 > :V4
```

etc.

So far, I have always advised users not to enter big interval dates so as to put a limit on the number of records resulted from the date index access path; however, from time to time it becomes necessary to specify bigger intervals.

If `V1, V2, ..., V750` were all low cardinality columns, I would have been able to utilize bitmap indexes. Unfortunately they are not.

What's the advice on this? How should I tackle this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: 750 numeric columns?  What the heck are you doing?  There's probably something smelly about your design, especially if it's a transactional database (which is implied from adding 20,000 rows per hour).  And I hope you know `BETWEEN` may not be getting the results the questors are looking for.

Comment: These columns have been produced automatically in this industrial environment. They measure equipment conditions and they are updated hourly. BETWEEN is suitable for them because they normally query for a specific period of time interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're stuck with the design, so a few thoughts that I'd probably look at -

1) use partitions - if you have partitioning option

2) use some triggers to denormalise (or normalise in this case) a query table which is more optimised for the query usage

3) make some snapshots

4) look at having a current table or set of tables which has the days records (or some suitable subset), and roll them over to a big table to store hsitory.

It depends on usage patterns and all the other constraints the system has - this may get you started, if you have more details a better solution is probably out there.

Answer (score 1):

I think the big problem would be the inserts. You have an index on sdate wich slow the inserts and speed up the selects. But, returning to your problems:

If users specify an interval wich is large (let's say >5%) it is beter to have the table partitioned by sdate in a daily or weekly or monthly manner. 
[Oracle partitioning docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm)

(If you partition the table, don't forget to partition also the index. And if you want to do it live, use `exchange partition` ).

Also, as workaround, if you have a powerfull machine, you may use parallel queries.
[Oracle Parallel docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/hintsref.htm#autoId9)

Comment: As data is inserted only once and queried many times, indexing the `SDATE` column makes sense and in fact load is not a problem for me (Server is also a powerful `Sun Fire E25K`). Also, the table is partitioned right now with locally partitioned indexes, though it is on a monthly basis. I admit this partitioning has been effective, but I am looking for something similar to bitmap indexes which helps with low-cardinality columns.

Comment: Hmmm... partitioning daily may help you(if you select many rows)... and also an index(sdate, NE)